# Is $f(z) \notin \Omega$ for all $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$ ? Yes/No

Tags: complex-analysis

let $\Omega =\{ w \in \mathbb{C} : |w- \frac{1}{4}| < \frac{1}{8} \} $ and  $f : \mathbb{C}  \to \mathbb{C}$  be  an entire  function  such that $ f(z) \notin \Omega$  for  all  $z \in \mathbb{C}$  . If $f(0) =1$, then

which of the  following statement(s)  is (are) true ?

$1.$$ f(z) = 1+z $ for all  $z$ in $\mathbb{C}.$

$2.$ $f(z) = 1+z+z^2 +...+z^n$  for all  $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$  and for  some $n \ge  2$

$3.$ $f(z)=e^z$  for all   $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$

$4.$ $f(z)=1$  for all  $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$

**My attempt** : option $4$ is obviously true because  $ 1 \notin \Omega$

option $1.$ is false  take  $z=\frac{1}{4}-1$

$f(z)= 1-\frac{1}{4}-1=\frac{1}{4} \in \Omega$

option $3.$ is false. Take $z =2 \log \frac{1}{2} \implies f= e^{2 \log \frac{1}{2}}= \frac{1}{4} \in \Omega$

I am confused about option $3 $

**My question** :Is $f(z) =1+z+z^2 +...+z^n\notin \Omega$  for all  $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$  ?

Comment: No, your reason for option 4. is not enough.

Comment: @DietrichBurde $f(z)=1$ is a  constant  function

Comment: Yes, but the assumptions may *not* imply that $f$ is constant. Why do you think they would?

Comment: okay @DietrichBurde  but  $1 \notin \Omega$

Comment: $|1-1/4 |> 1/8$  @DietrichBurde

Comment: Why does $1\not\in \Omega$ imply that $f(z)=1$ is constant? I don't see why you think that option 4. follows, i.e., is true.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Okay, got it you are right . I mean $f$ may be constant or may not be constant but not necessarily

Comment: Where did you get this problem from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider the function $$g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)-1/4}$$.

The image of f does not contain 1/4, so g is entire, and also $$|g(z)|\leq 8$$. Which theorem comes to your mind if a function is entire and bounded? Proceed from this.